# Extracting time from character string with strptime() in R, returning NA

Tags: regex, r, date, time, strptime

I am trying to extract out the time from a character string in R and can't stop getting NA as a result. I have tried numerous variations of the regular expression tags, but can't seem to get around this simple problem. Any help/clarifications are appreciated.

Here is my code for an example:

```
> x
[1] "2/7/2013 7:43"
> class(x)
[1] "character"
> z <- strptime(x, "%H:%M")
> z
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 14):

R doesn't know that your string is a datetime.  So make it one first:

```
y <- strptime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

If you were trying to get just the date, you could do:

```
strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Because `strptime` discards any extra characters past your format string, but you cannot grab the trailing `%H:%M` because the function doesn't know where to start.

Once it is a proper datetime class, you can do things to it:

```
strftime(y, '%H:%M')
```

I prefer to use `as.POSIXlt` rather than `strptime` and `format` instead of `strftime`... but they are roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to obtain a string with the time, you can use regular expressions in `sub`. If you use `strptime` on a string with no date information, today's date is used.

```
x <- "2/7/2013 7:43"

x2 <- sub(".* ", "", x)
# [1] "7:43"

strptime(x2, "%R")
# [1] "2014-02-05 07:43:00"
```

Comment: Can you explain to me the gist of the 3 regular expression items in the sub function? I am fairly new to regexpressions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @stokeinfo Have a look at `?sub`. The three arguments are: pattern, replacement, string. The pattern `.* ` means: Any number of characters followed by a space. The replacement is just the empty string. The function replaces the space and all characters preceding the space with the empty string. Hence, only the string denoting the time remains.

Comment: Or in other words, sub looks for the pattern and replaces it with "nothing", which effectively deletes the date from the string and just leaves the time?

Comment: Boom boom. Thank you very much!

Comment: Last thing out of curiosity... How would you extract the date with the same method?

Comment: @stokeinfo `sub(" .*", "", x)`