# Date/Time Separation

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning

I need to create a date column and a time column from a date time field.

**The structure of the data:**

```
Date.Time: POSIXct, format: "2017-04-01 05:17:02" "2017-04-01 05:18:20" "2017-04-01 05:25:24" "2017-04-01 05:31:46" .. data:
```

**I made this entry in R**

```
hour_min <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(FitFull$Date.Time,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",tz="",format = %H:%M)))
```

**And got this error message:**

```
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "hour_min <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(FitFull$Date.Time,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",tz="",format = %H:%"
```

Where can I go from here?  **"New R User"**

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585138/extracting-time-from-character-string-with-strptime-in-r-returning-na

Answer (score 0):

You've made several mistakes:

- The format in `strptime` is wrong. Is should be: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`.
- You don't need `strptime` and `as.POSIXct`. One of them is sufficient.
- The format-part of `format` is in the wrong spot and the format itself needs quotation-marks around it.

The correct specification is:

```
format(strptime("2017-04-01 05:17:02", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format = "%H:%M")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "05:17"
```

HTH